# Placing co-ordinates into a variable based on address entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am currently trying to allow users to type in a location and then reverse it into longitude and latitude coordinates which will then apply to latlng variable as opposed to set coordinates. At present I have a function that reverses the address entered into the SearchText into co-ordinates accordingly and alerts them. However I want to place these values within the latlng variable.

I am pretty new to this and am not sure how to go about it, does anyone have any ideas?
Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Melissa

```
<?php
 $var=$_POST['SearchText'];
 ?>

var address = "<?php echo $var ?>";

// AlertLatLng is a callback function which will be executed after converting address to coordinates
Convert_LatLng_To_Address(address, AlertLatLng);     

/*
* Alert Latitude & Longitude
*/
function AlertLatLng() {
    alert("The latitude is " + latitude + " and longitude is " + longitude);
}




    //Function that gets run when the document loads
    mel.initialize = function()
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.603791,-5.945412);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        //Sample call for yelp data for cafe's
        mel.getFlickr('<?php echo $var2 ?>');
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; margin-left:400px;"></div>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="SearchText" class="required-input" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search220" name="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: in `var lat = latitude; var long = longitude;` where does latitude and longitude get set?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you declare latlng at the top, you can set the value from within your callback. So something like

```
var latlng;

Convert_LatLng_To_Address(address, AlertLatLng);     

/*
* Alert Latitude & Longitude
*/
function AlertLatLng() {
    alert("The latitude is " + latitude + " and longitude is " + longitude);
    latlng = latitude + "," + longitude;
}
```

Which should set it as a string. It might be more useful to make latlng an array or even better Google has an object specifically for this:

```
latlng = new GLatLng(latitude ,longitude);
```

Comment: This totally makes sense but dosen't seem to work. It seems that the map completley disappears. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the map is disappearing it's probably due to an error somewhere. Also note that your functions to set the lat & long, and to display them are both called asynchronously. This means that you can't just add a line to access the variable in the main block of code because Javascript will probably get there before the functions have been called. So the code to do whatever it is you want to do with the coordinates should go in your callback AlertLagLng.